# Ubuntu Android Studio Cannot Launch Avd in Emulator

Tags: android, linux

```
/home/console/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_25

libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext

  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)

  Serial number of failed request:  49

  Current serial number in output stream:  48

libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext

  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)

  Serial number of failed request:  49

  Current serial number in output stream:  48

libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so

libGL error: driver pointer missing

libGL error: failed to load driver: r600

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so

libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)

  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)

  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)

  Value in failed request:  0x0

  Serial number of failed request:  33

  Current serial number in output stream:  34

QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

using Android Studio 2.2.2. Operating system is Ubuntu

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Android Studio comes with a libstdc++.so.6 that doesn't work properly together with Ubuntu. Forcing Android Studio to use the system's libstdc++.so.6 fixes this.

Android SDK Tools 25.2.x and earlier:

```
mv /opt/Android/SDK/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/Android/SDK/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

With the release of Android SDK Tools 25.3.0 the emulator has been moved to a separate package.

Android SDK Tools 25.3.0 and later:

```
mv /opt/Android/SDK/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6 /opt/Android/SDK/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Change the path `/opt/Android/SDK` in both lines to the location where you installed the Android SDK.

Note that you will (likely) have to repeat the process when you update the SDK (tools).